# Kivy and Raspberry PI

Tags: raspbian, python

I have an `RP13` with `Raspbian Jessie` and have tried to download and use with Python 3.4.2 IDE Kivy 1.9.1.

I have followed all the instructions as per the website, but cannot get the simple tutorial to run:

```
from kivy.app import App
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.uix.label import Label

class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Kivy 1 working")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

This comes up with  errors in the shell as below:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-09-04_4.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/kivy1.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/app.py", line 319, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/base.py", line 29, in <module>
     from kivy.clock import Clock
   File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/clock.py", line 364, in <module>
     from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, \
 ImportError: /home/pi/kivy/kivy/_clock.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

Any help/advice/suggestions/examples for new Piman.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following *minimal application* (from [Programming Guide » Kivy Basics](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html))?

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

You can save this to a text file, `main.py` for example, and run it.

Comment: That won't work either. The Error is in importing:
`from kivy.app import App`, as it states in the first line of his error.